# Portable Class Library Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, portable-class-library

I am currently trying to convert a Xamarin.iOS app library to a PCL (Profile 78). I have this code that will not compile:

```
 public static void RegisterAllCommandHandlers(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies) {
            // Get all types that are concrete classes which implement ICommandHandler
            var commandHandlerOpenGenericType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>);
            var types = new List<Type>();
            foreach (var assembly in assemblies) {
                types.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes()
                      .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && x.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == commandHandlerOpenGenericType)));
            }
    }
```

Here is an image of the compiler errors:
[image]

How can I do the same thing with the new reflection API?

Comment: Which platforms do you target in your PCL?

Comment: @Markus Profile 78 (Xamarin.IOS, Xamarin.Android, .net 4.5, windows store, windows phone 8

Comment: What are the compiler errors you get? (The image does not show the compiler errors).

Comment: @elgonzo "Cannot resolve symbol" for each item in red

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is due to the type/typeinfo split.  See [Evolving the Reflection API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx).

Try this code:

```
assembly.DefinedTypes
    .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && x.ImplementedInterfaces
        .Any(i => i.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == commandHandlerOpenGenericType))
    .Select(x => x.AsType())
```