# Using activator to get an instance from interface on a portable class project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, portable-class-library, activator

Any idea on how to do this in a portable class? 't' does not seem to have IsInterface or IsAbstract nor does Type have IsAssignableFrom.

I am trying to activate an instance from an interface inside a portable class library project so I can use it inside Xamarin.

I tried this code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732933/can-i-use-activator-createinstance-with-an-interface) but it does not work as a lot of stuff are not there in the portable projects

*Code from question:*

```
Type[] iLoadTypes = (from t in Assembly.Load("ClassLibrary1").GetExportedTypes()
                 where !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract
                 where typeof(ILoad).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                 select t).ToArray();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portable class library has some updates in the Assembly and Type classes.
Here is the code needed to do what you wanted in a portable class project.

```
Type[] interfaceTypes = (from t in Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("DependencyInjectionClient")).ExportedTypes
                                             where !t.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface && !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract
                                             where typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t.GetTypeInfo())
                                             select t).ToArray();
```

The information you needed was moved to the [TypeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

The answer was found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524263/portable-class-library-reflection) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061291/portable-class-library-and-reflection)
which leaded to [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api/)